# How to show MySQL databases on a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a list of all the databases on my server, when I do this:

```
echo mysql_query(" SHOW DATABASES ");
```

I get this error:

```
Resource id #3
```

So how to do it?

Comment: Same way you handle every other query that returns rows?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) or a tutorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to retrieve a result set from the query, like so:

```
$set = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES;');
$dbs = array();
while ($db = mysql_fetch_row($set))
{
   $dbs[] = $db[0];
}
echo implode('<br/>', $dbs);
```

Answer (score 8):

It's clear that you're new to PHP, so here's a huge tip.

The "mysql" extension is old and busted.  Don't use it, and stop reading any tutorials that tell you it's the thing to use.

Instead, [learn PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it works for most database engine and *helps you do the right thing*.  Here's an example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;user=foo;password=bar;dbname=baz');
$statement = $dbh->query('SHOW DATABASES');
print_r( $statement->fetchAll() );
```

Comment: what about mysqli? would you still prefer PDO? Thanks

Comment: mysqli's wacky `bind_param` is a detriment to simple workflows.  I vastly prefer PDO's `execute` method and the ability to simply pass an array of values in.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give PDO a shot and see how i like it

Comment: If needed is a list of all databases why should we have to first give credentials for just one of those databases?

Comment: The "dbname" parameter is optional.

Answer (score 3):

Jacob Relkin's solution is very good.

However, if you are using MySQL 5.x, I would only change one thing:

Instead of using SHOW DATABASES; I would use this query

SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;

Comment: Can you please offer a explanation?

Comment: `information_schema` is a standardized cross-database way to ask about schemas (databases in MySQL-speak), tables, views, columns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To list just the useful Databases, and not the system ones:

```
$query = "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name
    NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema')";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$dbs = array();
while($db = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   $dbs[] = $db[0];
echo implode('<br/>', $dbs);
```

Your MySQL user should have full access, otherwise you will see only the databases where you have at least read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you're getting a query result set. You need to retrieve the result rows like this:

```
$r = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

that aught to do it