# How to display list of databases present on your localhost server

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

How to display list of databases present on your localhost server

Comment: mysqli_query("SHOW DATABASES");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had existed here (by another person), You can try it here:
[How to show MySQL databases on a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240732/how-to-show-mysql-databases-on-a-php-script)

and 
[php mysqli list databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677279/php-mysqli-list-databases)

and finally
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

SELECT    schema_name    FROM information_schema.schemata

Answer (score 0):

show all database just use
   SHOW DATABASES